# Syntax error executing if - else statement when else is equal to NULL

Tags: mysql, if-statement, null

The column Old_Price is used to determine the column Increased_Price by adding 10% if Old_Price is less than $10 otherwise it's null.

```
SELECT Copy_Price, 
  IF (Old_Price < 10.00, 
      Increased_Price = (Old_Price + (Old_Price * 0.1))
  ELSE Increased_Price = NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want see the result in increased_price column  just use select

```
SELECT Copy_Price, IF(Old_Price < 10.00, Old_Price + (Old_Price * 0.1), null) Increased_Price 
from my_table
```

otherwise if you want store the result in the table  then use update  and set

```
update my_table 
set Increased_Price =  IF (Old_Price < 10.00, Old_Price + (Old_Price * 0.1), null)
```